# Guardar data en API

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, reactjs, entity-framework

Me encuentro con estos problemas, espero me puedan ayudar. Según puedo ver, todo está bien y no entiendo porque no me permite guardar. Adjuntaré estos errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo `doctorProfileImg` en mi base de datos (SQL Server) es de tipo `varbinary(max)` y el otro campo es de tipo `string`.  Intento guardar esto desde **React** , además de otros campos claro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y finalmente les dejo mi código:
**POST Controller**

```js
// POST: api/TDoctors
[HttpPost]
public async Task <IActionResult> PostTDoctor([FromBody] TDoctor tDoctor) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _context.TDoctor.Add(tDoctor);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetTDoctor", new { id = tDoctor.DoctorId }, tDoctor);
}
```

En el modelo está así:

```js
public byte[] DoctorProfileImg { get; set; }
public string DoctorPhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

Cargo los datos de los inputs en el state de esta forma:

```javascript
handleChange = (e) => {
    const state = this.state;
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        ...state,
    });
};

handleFileChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
        file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    });
};

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const URL = "http://localhost:55317/api/TDoctors/";

    const DATA = {
        doctorName: this.state.name,
        doctorProfileImg: this.state.file,
        doctorPhoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
        doctorEmail: this.state.email,
        doctorStatus: this.state.status,
        doctorSpecialtyId: Number(this.state.specialty),
    };

    ApiService.post(URL, DATA)
        .then(() => this.props.history.push("/doctors"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

En cuanto al **ApiService** , está creado de esta forma:

```javascript
static post = async (url, obj) => {
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    const data = await response.json();

    return data;
};
```

El error que me sale en la consola del navegador, es este:

```
> ApiService.js:50 POST http://localhost:55317/api/TDoctors/ 400 (Bad Request)
push../src/services/ApiService.js.ApiService.post   @   ApiService.js:50
AddDoctor.handleSubmit  @   AddDoctor.js:62
```

A qué se debe el problema?? no encuentro la solución a esto. En cuanto a `doctorPhoneNumber`, más aún no encuentro razón, porque solo es de tipo texto... he revisado en el **React Developers Tools** , y los datos se cargan correctamente en el **state** , la imagen en formato **blob** y tenía entendido que el `varbinary(max)` es una forma "moderna" de cargar datos **blob** en SQL Server.

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Usted esta usando Entity Framework y le esta devolviendo un Bad Request porque si se fija en su controlador se esta validando el modelo :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

Y esto esta pasando porque el modelo que esta recibiendo de react no concuerda con el modelo de C#. Por tanto debe modificar el modelo de el API algo similar a este, solamente revise los tipos de datos que debe llevar cada propiedad y que concuerden con los que le esta enviando de js:

```
public class TDoctor{
    public byte[]  doctorProfileImg{ get; set; }
      public string  doctorPhoneNumber{ get; set; }
      public string  doctorEmail{ get; set; }
       public string doctorStatus{ get; set; }
       public string doctorSpecialtyId{ get; set; }
}
```

Si ya tiene el modelo de esta forma entonces intente hacer un POST pero sin el contenido de la imagen , es decir enviar todos los datos desde js excepto el contenido de la imagen. Si le funciona sin el contenido de la imagen es porque el contenido no es compatible con el arreglo de bites del modelo.
Y también asegurese que los demas datos que se envian son del mismo tipo que el del modelo definido en C#.

Comment: Si he probado sin enviar la imagen y si guarda los datos. Claro, colocando el "Content-Type" para JSON. Cómo podría hacer si quiero con la imagen? gracias.

Comment: Hagale un console.log() a lo que tiene la imágen en el json antes de enviarse al API, para ver que tipo de base 64 se esta enviando o que valor se esta enviando. Pareciera que a ese event.target.files[0]  le falta un .result : event.target.files[0].result pero no estoy seguro por eso ocupo ver que se esta enviando ahí